# Login to Google without Google+ login button but user credentials

Tags: android, youtube-api, google-plus, gdata, google-data-api

I have a specific problem, the application is only for a set of people whose Google credentials are on my server. I make a login to my server, look-up the Google credentials and send them back and Create an OAuth authentication to interact with Google services. (Because I don't want the app to be device specific I want to use accounts other than those registered on my device, which completely fails in a G+ sign in mechanism) 
Currently I use a Deprecated Client ID mechanism wherein I pass the Uname and Pwd to [g-data java client](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/trunk/java/sample/youtube/)

What would be the preferred way and if there are any other ways to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YouTube does not want to support username/password based login on behalf of users, because this introduces all kinds of security concerns. You should use OAuth from a device when possible. You should NOT be caching user passwords on your server.

Comment: Thank you very much! Although the Google Id's in my case are all open with the consent of people using them. I believe respecting privacy is of utmost concern here and its well understood.